# PreferenceActivity gives a NullPointerException when option selected from ListPreference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-preferences

I'm new to using the PreferenceActivity.

**Task:** Allow user to choose the program layout from the Preferences

**Problem:** Selecting an option in the PreferenceList causes a NullPointerException

**Exception arises:** At android.preference.ListPreference.onDialogClosed()

[image]

(Shortened) Code:

```
private static final String PREF_LAYOUT_KEY = "PrefLayout";
private static final int DEFAULT_LAYOUT = LayoutHelper.LAYOUT_DOUBLE ;
private static int mListLayout = DEFAULT_LAYOUT ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    mListLayout = pref.getInt(PREF_LAYOUT_KEY, DEFAULT_LAYOUT);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences pref,
        String key) {

    Log.v(TAG, "OnSharedPreferencesChanged run" ); // TODO Testing Purposes

    if( key.equals( PREF_LAYOUT_KEY ) ){
        mListLayout = pref.getInt(key, DEFAULT_LAYOUT);
    }
}
```

[PreferenceActivity]

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
    }
}
```

[res/xml/pref.xml]

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/pref_cat1_title">

    <ListPreference
        android:title="@string/pref_layout_name"
        android:summary="@+id/pref_chosen_layout"
        android:key="PrefLayout"
        android:entries="@array/prefLayoutOptions"
        android:entryValues="@array/prefLayoutOptionsValues"
    />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

[Strings.xml]

```
<string name="pref_cat1_title">Layout</string>
    <string name="pref_layout_name">"Layout of list"</string>
        <array name="prefLayoutOptions">
            <item>Layout 1 (single)</item>
            <item>Layout 2 (double)</item>
            <item>Layout 3 (triple)</item>
            <item>Layout 4 (quad)</item>
        </array>
        <array name="prefLayoutOptionsValues">
            <item>50</item>
            <item>51</item>
            <item>52</item>
            <item>53</item>
        </array>
```

The bit of code that logs OnSharedPreferencesChanged being run never gets there.

Can anybody see where I've gone wrong?

EDIT. Here's the top of the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2707): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2707):        at android.preference.ListPreference.onDialogClosed(ListPreference.java:218)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2707):        at android.preference.DialogPreference.onDismiss(DialogPreference.java:384)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2707):        at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2707):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: You say that the exception is in .onDialogClosed() but I can't see this method in your code...

Comment: Can you post a LogCat output?

Comment: Just added the stack trace. @Sephy: The onDialogClosed is from the ListPreference, not my own code

Comment: Does this happens too when you clcik the cancel button or back button? or only when you select something?

Comment: Only when I select an option from the list. I'm pretty sure it's to do with committing the information to memory because there is no code to tell it which SharedPreferences file to store information to

Comment: Does the log "OnSharedPreferencesChanged run" get prompted when you click an item? or does it crashes before that?

Comment: It crashes before it gets to that code (mentioned at the bottom of the question)

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541200/accessing-a-class-from-another-activity/3541229#3541229

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
mListLayout = pref.getInt(PREF_LAYOUT_KEY, DEFAULT_LAYOUT);
```

That will fail, because the preference is a string, not an int.

```
<array name="prefLayoutOptions">
<array name="prefLayoutOptionsValues">
```

Change these to `<string-array>`. Here is [a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/) demonstrating the use of a `ListPreference`.

Comment: Changing the arrays to string-arrays seems to fix the problem, but I'd have to change my classes to deal with Strings instead. I'd really like to store these preferences as ints, do you know what I would need to change to have everything working with ints?

Comment: @T3Roar: `ListPreference` supports strings. If you want something else, you will need to write your own preference class.

Comment: or you can have a hashmap in your class to map the string with the ints if that's really what you need.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem. It seems you can only use string values:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2096

/Håkan

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set preference change listener for your preferences right at the activity, try putting that to the activity's onCreate:

```
    Map<String, ?> prefs = this.getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().getAll();
    for (String preferenceName : prefs.keySet()) {
        Preference p = this.findPreference(preferenceName);
        if (p != null) {
            Object value = prefs.get(preferenceName);
            p.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which activity are you referring to? It has errors for both the main activity or the Preferences activity

Comment: On second thought, I would prefer to find the root of the problem than to do this kind of hack to fix it. Although it has tipped me off to hunt down another bit of access to shared preferences which may be interfering